# Size Error when attempting to plot with pyplot barbs

Tags: python, matplotlib, size, cartopy

I have an xarray.DataArray I want to plot on top of a cartopy map of the United States with u and v winds (barbs) at evenly spaced latitude and longitude points. I'm indexing my wind data to not plot every point (like every 5th) to do so. However, when I go to run my plot, I am getting this error:

```
"X and Y must be the same size, but X.size is 45 and Y.size is 81."
```

Here is the basics of the code with the data and my attempt at using the plt.barbs() function. I believe I am to call my latitude and longitude points in place of the X and Y variables in plt.barbs(). However, the error is arising when latitude is 45 points and longitude is 81. I'm also using a function to call the u_array and v_array's to plug into the plot. Am I not using it correctly or is there another issue with sizing of the data?

```
    data = 'VARIABLE'
    data = data.sel(latitude=slice(latmax,latmin), longitude=slice(lonmin,lonmax))
    lats = data['latitude']
    lons = data['longitude']
    u = u_array*10
    v = v_array*10
    plt.barbs(lats[::5],lons[::5],u,v)
```

And below is an example of the u_wind from my data

```
xarray.DataArray'U_Wind'latitude: 45longitude: 401
array([[ 5.40691456e-03,  5.15891418e-03,  5.06325975e-03, ...,
         4.76794612e-03,  4.75683032e-03,  4.76837835e-03],
       [-1.43884958e-03, -1.18659466e-03, -8.66431906e-04, ...,
         4.50176722e-03,  4.41688955e-03,  4.33127597e-03],
       [ 1.62759619e-04,  5.66036437e-05, -6.58664997e-05, ...,
         4.82692387e-03,  4.81484310e-03,  4.59895644e-03],
       ...,
       [-2.11682637e-02, -2.12768081e-02, -2.13602273e-02, ...,
         1.28550304e-02,  1.25738495e-02,  1.23849878e-02],
       [-2.30783832e-02, -2.31578710e-02, -2.32645631e-02, ...,
         1.65182475e-02,  1.59745798e-02,  1.54944955e-02],
       [-2.58581950e-02, -2.59413023e-02, -2.60206995e-02, ...,
         1.88876221e-02,  1.89447670e-02,  1.90456638e-02]])
```

I tried to index the latitude and longitude points to exactly match each other's shape, but that is simply too inefficient.